# "owner" account start with a non-zero DAI balance in Hardhat test suite

Tags: ethereum, erc20, ethers.js, hardhat

I'm writing unit tests using Hardhat's mainnet fork, and for a test I want to assert that the initial DAI balance for the `owner` account is 0. However when the code reaches the assertion `assert(ownerDai.isZero());`, the assertion fails. Here's the test:

```js
const { assert } = require("chai");
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");
const ERC20ABI = require('../external_ABI/ERC20.json'); // ERC20 abi for interacting with DAI

const DAI_ADDRESS = "0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f";

describe("SimpleTest", function () {
    it("Test that owner DAI balance is 0", async function () {
        const provider = ethers.provider;
        const [owner] = await ethers.getSigners();
        const DAI = new ethers.Contract(DAI_ADDRESS, ERC20ABI, provider);

        ownerDaiBalance = await DAI.balanceOf(owner.address);
        assert(ownerDaiBalance.isZero()); // Assertion fails here
    });
});
```

If I print `ownerDaiBalance` to console it shows that the balance is actually equal to 10008133730236507217. Why is `ownerDaiBalance` non-zero to start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turns out that at block #14189520, which is the block I'm forking off of, the `owner` account *actually does* have some DAI on the Ethereum mainnet. It's only $10 worth of DAI, but this explains why I was getting a initial balance of 1000813373023650721 instead of 0 as expected.

I added `owner` to my mainnet Metamask account and it turns out that `owner` also has other ERC20 tokens:

[image: owner account balance]

I guess gas fees are too high right now for anyone to consider transferring these funds out.

Anyway, as a workaround, I've added `addr1` as a second account for the unit test, which does *not* have any DAI to start with:

```js
const [owner, addr1] = await ethers.getSigners();
```